# Dropzone.js Remove "Drop files here or click to upload." when file is uploading

Tags: dropzone.js

How can I remove the instructional text "Drop files here or click to upload." when a file is being uploaded? I've included some screenshots to demonstrate below.

#### Default - no file (for demo purposes)

[image: Default - no file]

#### Default - uploading file (behaviour I would like)

[image: Default - with file]

#### Mine - no file

[image: Mine - no file]

#### Mine - uploading file (I don't want the text)

[image: Mine - with file]

#### CSS

```
.dropzone {
    border: none !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    background: white !important;
    min-height: 200px !important;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #263238;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

#### Javascript

```
$(document).bind('drop dragover', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var myvue = new Vue({
    el: 'body',

    ready: function () {
        var dropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, {
            url: "/api/import",
            previewsContainer: ".dropzone",
            clickable: ".dropzone",
            init: function () {
                this.on("success", function (file, response) {
                    console.log(file);
                    console.log(response);
                });
            },
            paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
            maxFilesize: 4, // MB
            acceptedFiles: ".csv",
            uploadMultiple: false,
            maxFiles: 1,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Try with this css rule: `.dz-max-files-reached .dz-message { display: none;}`. Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/sLgx20dx/1/

Comment: Still the same issue. I must have changed something somewhere. I'll have a look and report back.

Comment: And @Mike was never seen again

Answer (score 0):

No expert, but here's what I figured out, for anyone else like me who finds this perfect question with no answer.

When initialising Dropzone, the first param is the element where files can be dropped:

`let myDropzone = new Dropzone('#droppable-element', configData);`

When you add a file, dropzone's `added()` function it checks if the `#droppable-element` is also the `previewsContainer` (set in `configData`). If so, it adds the `dz-started` class to that element.

https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/blob/f50d1828ab5df79a76be00d1306cc320e39a27f4/src/options.js#L612

Then, `dropzone.css` applies the following:

```
.dropzone.dz-started .dz-message {
    display: none;
}
```

If, like me, you're not using dropzone's css, you can implement the same css yourself.

If your `#droppable-element` is not also your preview, you could make use to the event's and add a class to your message element when files are added/removed.

Hope this helps someone